# Node upgrade pop up showing in the worker nodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In one cluster we have 2 nodes available. in the past few weeks I see the pop up says to upgrade the Node version.

Now, my question if i upgrade to the new version will this going to effect the node or not? if yes what are all steps I need to take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i upgrade to the new version will this going to effect the node or
>   not?

If you're asking whether **master-node** upgrade will automatically upgrade your **worker-nodes**, the answer is - it depends if you have **auto-upgrade** feature enabled. If yes, your **worker nodes** will be automatically upgraded but it may happen at any time. If you want to heve more controll over the upgrade process, you can do it manually.

**Master-node** and **worker-node** upgrades on **GKE** are performed separately. Note that your **worker-nodes** can never have newer version than is installed on your **master-node**. For this reason you always upgrade your **master-node** first. The whole **GKE** cluster upgrade operation boils down to two simple steps that you may perform from **GCP console**:

1. go to **Kubernetes engine** -> click your **cluster name** -> click **upgrade available** link next to your **master version** -> select the required version -> click **change**.
2. Once **master-node** is upgraded you will be able to easily upgrade your **worker/workers** to the same version as your **master** is already running. Simply go again to **Kubernetes engine** -> then you may simply click `Node upgrade available` link: [image] Note that this link wasn't even available when the version on your **worker-nodes** was the same as version on your **master-node**. Select the required version and click **change**. Alternatively you may go to **Kubernetes engine** -> click your cluster name -> go to the bottom of the page -> click onto your node-pool (by default named: **default-pool**) -> click **Edit** -> select the required version -> click **change**.

Within a **node pool**, nodes are upgraded **one at a time**, in an undefined order. Context documentation explains what actually happens:

> Changing the Kubernetes version drains, deletes, and recreates all
>   nodes in this node pool one at a time. The operation has the following
>   effects:
>
> - Only Pods managed by controllers are automatically recreated.
> - Temporary storage volumes are deleted. Persistent disks are unaffected.
> - Your workloads might be temporarily unavailable during the operation.
> - You cannot make changes to the cluster configuration during the operation.

More information about **GKE** upgrades you can fine in the following articles in **GCP official docs**:

[Cluster upgrades](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades)

[Auto-upgrading nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades)